# laravel 4 - subdomains - session lost after Redirect::action()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have to redirect in `CompanyController->create()`:

```
class CompanyController extends \BaseController {
...
public function index(){
    echo var_dump(Session::get('err'));
}
...
public function create()
{
    if($validator->passes()){
        $this->setError("no errors");
    }else{
        $this->setError("Some errors occurred: ");
        foreach($validator->messages()->all() as $msg) 
            $this->setError($msg);
    }
    return Redirect::action('CompanyController@index');
    }
}
```

My BaseController class looks like this:

```
class BaseController extends Controller {
    private $errors = array();
    protected $view_params = array();
    function __construct() {
        if(Session::has('err')){
            $this->errors = Session::get('err');
            $this->view_params['err'] = $this->errors;
        }
    }
    ...

    protected function setError($str){
        if(!isset($this->view_params['err']) || $this->view_params['err']==null)
            $this->view_params['err']=array();
        if(!isset($this->errors) || $this->errors==null)
            $this->errors=array();
        array_push($this->view_params['err'],$str);
        array_push($this->errors,$str);
        Session::put('err',$this->errors);
    }
    protected function getErrors(){
        return $this->errors;
    }
}
```

The `CompanyController->index()` function displays always `NULL`. why?

**EDIT**
my session settings are:

```
'driver' => 'native',
'lifetime' => 0,
'domain' => '.domain.com',
```

Comment: Try once without any custom session settings (just using the defaults). Does it work?

Answer (score 0):

restoring the default setting values of the `config/session.php`, solved the problem!

so, now, configs are:

```
'driver' => 'native',
'lifetime' => 0,
'domain' => null,
```